# How can I clean these small, enclosed gutters on a mobile home patio?

Tags: cleaning, maintenance, gutters

My friend owns a mobile home that has a patio over the front porch. There is a thin gutter system running along the length of the house & porch, terminating over the porch area. The gutter system appears to be almost completely enclosed and is so backed up with dirt & debris that no water makes it through the spout.

Is there a good way of cleaning out this gutter system?

[image: Gutters]

Comment: wow, that's not supposed to be like that. using supports for drains means it looks crooked or won't actually drain. you want the water to flow a few inches past the horizontal beam. If it's like the one across the street, that's not happening. i bet those hollow columns are nothing but rust. anyway, it's not ideal for cleaning either. i would try a power washer, leaf blower, or shop vac.

Comment: They're NOT using the supports for drains. The drains are beside the supports.

Comment: That "support" on the far left is indeed the drain, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I have a mobile home with these terrible enclosed gutters. When the leafs and crap are  dry, use a leaf blower or a shop vac to clean. I get up on a ladder and loosen stuff in gutter with a screw driver .After this, vacuum or blow . Then run waterer through gutter to get rest of crap out.

Really is a dirty, wet mess but has to be done.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar awning and gutter on my house. I think I'm going to have to take the ends loose and pull them back and run a water house down one end and wash everything out the other end.  It sucks but I don't know what else to do.  Now it is running over in the middle, pooling on the ground, and seeping into my crawlspace.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 2):

Well I have this issue and mine have too many screws in the wood cover.  This is what I do.  When it is raining, a hard rain, I get out me ladder and push the dirt and the rain help push it out the drain.  Other than that you can take a hose and run water but it takes longer. The dirt remains solid if you can't push it out.

Answer (score 1):

I use a blower to blow out stuff from the same type of gutters on my Moms mobile home then I run water to get the rest of dirt out of the gutters.

Answer (score 1):

That stuff doesn't conveniently blow or wash out.  After several seasons of wetting and drying, "gutter sod" has the consistency of shredded wheat biscuit, and is essentially one house-length vegetable brick hardened into your gutter system.  Dry, you must manually break it up, inch by inch, then try and blow it out.  Wet, it must still be broken up with some type of hooked or prodding instrument, then vigorously washed out.  M E S S.